# Multithreading error when using conditions in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

The project I am working on requires that theoretical ships be docked at ports that have capacity limits, and while they're at these ports, passengers board them and take rides to their destinations. Each ship is a different thread, simply going in a loop docking at all the ports, and each passenger is a thread trying to get to every port on their itinerary.

The problem arises when a ship is waiting for space to become available at a port. I am using a condition that should wait until the number of ships at a port is less than the ports capacity.

```
def dock(ship)
@portLock.synchronize{
    @portCond.wait_until {ships.size < size}
        @ships.push(ship)
        ship.set_port(self)
        prnt("#{ship.to_s} docking at #{self.to_s}")
    @portCond.broadcast
}
end
```

This is my current version of the method and as of now. In this, the other ships never wake up besides the one running. In other cases, I get an error that looks like this: `mon_check_owner': current thread not owner (ThreadError). I have no clue what this means and Google has not helped. Could someone please explain how to use conditions in ruby correctly and what is going wrong. Thanks in advance.